# Touchwiz deleted Galaxy S Duos. Phone doesnt work beyond language setting

Tags: screen, delete, samsung-touchwiz

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Duos with Root access. Recently I removed Touchwiz through Root Uninstaller. After uninstalling, the phone screen went blank. The only thing visible was the notification bar with basic options.

I tried to restart the device but nothing happened. I recently did a hard reset on my GT-S7562. After reset the phone booted up, I did the Initial set up (language, wi-fi, time). Now a black screen shows up displaying the battery status, time network strength and nothing else.

If I press the back key the set up starts all over again. No home screen, no app drawer. Nothing except a "black" screen. I tried another reset and the same thing happened.

What do I do now?

Comment: A friendly advice: Do not remove any pre-installed app unless you have a [tag:Nandroid] backup or you **exactly**  know what you're doing and dealing with?

Answer (score 2):

1. Grab yourself a stock-firmware from sammobile.com or from the xda
   forum.
2. Install Odin v3.XX on your PC, start Odin and boot your phone into the download Mode ( Volume Down + Power )
3. Use Odin to flash the stock firmware onto your phone, wait until it is completed
4. Restart your device and set it up from the beginning
5. Optional: Root it again and next time - install a different launcher - you don't need to deinstall the whole touchwiz framework - I'm surprised that the systemui was still funcitonal.